# TFS Changeset "Roll-up" / Cumulative Report

Tags: tfs, version-control

I need to have several changesets rolled-up into a single list of changed files, so that I can code-review the collective differences (from an initial changeset, up through an arbitrary ending changeset), rather than reviewing all changes through the individual intervening changesets.

I'm using VS 2k8.  What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to open a Visual Studio explorer window, and type this:

```
tf folderdiff "$/MyStuffInSource;C88986~C91716" /recursive
```

That causes a window to open that shows the added, removed, changed files - and allows diffs to be launched on the individual files.  Superb!!

Comment: ...and it can be done through the IDE as well.  Just right click on a source explorer folder, and select "compare..." option.  Make the source and destination point to the same location, then adjust the changesets being used.